# How to install Xfce from tarball (source code) in OpenBSD without internet access?

Tags: software-installation, xfce, openbsd

I downloaded the Xfce tar.bz2 tarball file and I want to install Xfce. I can't install from the internet because of problems with my connection to the Internet. Who can help me to install Xfce from tarball (source code) in OpenBSD without internet access?

Comment: I would suggest reading https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/ports.html . The page has a lot of information for installing ports (software that is compiled). It also has an example where rsnapshot is installed. You should also look at their man pages and faq, the dev team puts a lot of effort in making their documentation good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: Install the pre-built `xfce` package.

---

There's unfortunately no way getting around the fact that you need to
download Xfce *and all needed dependencies for building it*, if you
really want to install from source.

On OpenBSD, you should ideally install the `xfce` package.  This is a
"meta package" that installs everything you need to get a working Xfce
desktop up and running on OpenBSD.

```
$ doas pkg_add xfce
```

On an otherwise vanilla OpenBSD system, this would install the 148 separate packages required to run Xfce.

For a *minimal* working Xfce environment, you may instead choose to install the following packages:

- xfce4-panel
- xfce4-session
- xfce4-settings
- xfconf
- xfdesktop
- thunar
- xfwm4

Installing these separately would also pull in dependent packages obviously, but probably not as many as 148 packages in total.

---

To build from source on OpenBSD, your best bet is to build the
`meta/xfce` port.  You may fetch *all* needed distribution sources for this port in
one go when you have a good internet connection, and then build when you
have time.  Note that this will likely require you to fetch *far more*
data than installing the binary packages since it also includes fetching the distribution sources for the build dependencies.

To fetch all sources for all ports needed for building the `meta/xfce` port, I assume that you have [the ports file hierarchy                                                      checked out under `/usr/ports`](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/ports.html#PortsFetch) and that you are [generally acquainted with how to build ports on OpenBSD](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/index.html).  You should then use the [*Distributed
Ports Builder*, `dpb`](http://man.openbsd.org/dpb), to fetch all required dist-files:

```
$ doas /usr/ports/infrastructure/bin/dpb -F 4 meta/xfce
```

This would fetch all needed dist-files, four at a time.

Once you have downloaded everything, you may build and install Xfce
off-line with

```
$ cd /usr/ports/meta/xfce
$ doas make install
```

Instead of doing this on the main meta port, you may also choose to do this on the seven ports needed to install a *minimal* Xfce desktop (listed above, but you will need to prefix each one of them with `x11/xfce4/`).

---

If you *really* need to build from your own Xfce sources, for example if this is a newer version of the software, then I strongly suggest that you make contact with Landry Breuil (who is the current port maintainer), and collaborate with him to update the port (and any dependencies that may need tweaking for a new version of Xfce).  His contact details may be found with

```
$ cd /usr/ports/meta/xfce
$ make show=MAINTAINER
```